# Core Data one to many record insert error

Tags: core-data

I have three entities

```
Forms{
    name:string
    jobs<-->>JSAjobs.form
}

JSAjobs{
    name:string
    form<<-->Forms.jobs
}

Jobs{
    step:string
    jobs<<-->Forms.jobs
}
```

I am getting this error:

> to-many relationship fault "jobs" for objectID 0x95afe60. . .  fulfilled from database.  Got 0 rows

Now I save the row for Forms entity first later on I need to fetch the last record on the Form entity create a new row on `JSAjobs` with details on `JSAjop` like next

Thanks

```
    NSMutableArray *jobData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:controller.jobData];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"JSAform" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *testForFalse = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emailed == NO"];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:testForFalse];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSLog(@"Fetched Rows: %i", [fetchedObjects count]);

//NSManagedObject *existingParent= //... results of a fetch
JSAform *lastForm = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

JSAjobs *newJobs = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"JSAjobs" inManagedObjectContext:context];
// Setting new values
newJobs.jobType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [jobData objectAtIndex:0]];
newJobs.jobName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[jobData objectAtIndex:1]objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]];
newJobs.comments = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[jobData objectAtIndex:1]objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]];
newJobs.date = [NSDate date];
[newJobs setValue:lastForm forKey:@"form"];

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

//New SOP Value
JOBsop *jobSOP = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"JOBsop" inManagedObjectContext:context];
for (int i = 0; i< [[jobData objectAtIndex:1]count]; i++){
    NSLog(@"Value for key: %i", i);
    if (i > 0){
        for (int k = 0; k< [[[jobData objectAtIndex:1]objectAtIndex:i] count]; k++){

            jobSOP.step = [[[jobData objectAtIndex:1]objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:k];
            [jobSOP setValue:newJobs forKey:@"jobs"];
       // [NSNumber numberWithInt:[txtBoots.text integerValue]];
        NSLog(@"Simple key: %@", [[[jobData objectAtIndex:1]objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:k]);
        }
    }
}
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Sorry I have a mistake in the relationship pseudocode

Comment: Sorry I have a mistake in the relationship pseudocode is this way
Forms{ name:string jobs<-->>JSAjobs.form }
JSAjobs{ name:string steps<-->>jobsDetail.jobs }Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entities are very confusing because you did not pick usable entity names. You were too confused to lay out these simple relationships yourself. This results in chaotic code and does not allow you to think things through in a structured way.

Your code is completely incomprehensible. You have a data array despite a fetched results controller (presumably). The second part of your code sports a mysterious and cryptic new entity `JOBsob`. No way you can ask a meaningful question like this, let alone get an answer.

You have nested arrays without any type checking which is bound to break and in any way completely impossible to debug. Get rid of all of these.

Nevertheless, let's five it a try to get you started:

First, it does not make sense to use the plural for the entity name. If the entity represents a "form", it should be `Form` not `Forms`.

Maybe you want this setup:

```
Form <<----> Job <----->> JobDetail
```

One job has many forms and many job details. So the Form has a relationship `job` while the Job has a relationship `forms`. Similarly, a Jobdetail has a relationship `job` while Job has a relationship `details`.

When you have a form and create a new job you can only assign one job to it. Thus, the old job (if any) relationship would be broken.

```
oldForm.job = newJob;
```

This is a much safer way to assign relationships. Of course, you have created NSManagedObject subclasses for these entities for this purpose.

If however, the relationship between Job and Form is one-to-many in the other direction, your scheme would look like this.

```
Form <---->> Job <------>> JobDetail
```

I do not really now what a "form" would mean in this case - I will just rename it `Project` for clarity.

```
Project <---->> Job <------>> JobDetail
```

Now you can assign the a new job to a project and link the other relationships like this:

```
newJob.project = existingProject; 
newJobDetail.job = newJob;
```

Comment: I have to said **Many Thanks** for your explanation, I reorganized the structures as you suggests, everything works perfect.